# Android: Drop Shadow like google now editext box "Exactly"

Tags: android, google-now

Like [this](http://www.engadget.com/2012/11/22/google-now-innovation-of-the-year/)

I found tutorial [here](http://codebybrian.com/2013/05/05/adding_dropshadow_to_android_view.html)

but is it not exactly like google now edit text box.

How to make drop shadow on edit text like google now.

Now my code is

> ```
>     <shape android:shape="rectangle">
>         <padding android:bottom="1dp" />
>
>         <gradient
>             android:angle="90"
>             android:centerX="20%"
>             android:centerColor="#878686"
>             android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
>             android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
>             android:type="linear"
>             />
>         <corners android:radius="8dp" />
>     </shape>
> </item>
>
>
> <item
>     android:left="0dp"
>     android:right="0dp"
>     android:top="0dp"
>     android:bottom="10dp">
>     <shape android:shape="rectangle">
>         <solid android:color="@color/pure_white_transparent"/>
>         <corners android:radius="2dp" />
>     </shape>
> </item> </layer-list>
> ```

Comment: Why don't you use a 9 patch for active state ?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850726/add-drop-shadow-effects-to-edittext-field

Comment: No, that is not look like google now shadow effect. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your edittext :

```
   android:shadowColor="#0000ff"
   android:shadowDx="2"
   android:shadowDy="4"
```