# How to add a blurred shadow to an edit text?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add a blurred shadow for my edit text but I don't know how?
I had made the shape but I don't know the attribute for adding blur to the edit text.
I made a drawable resource file and make this as a background to my edit text but it doesn't look as the picture
and this my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- "shadow" -->
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#E8E9ED"
                />

            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>


    <item android:bottom="5px"
        android:left="5px"
        android:right="5px"
        android:top="5px">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attributes: `android:shadowColor`, `android:shadowRadius`, `android:shadowDx`, and `android:shadowDy` create text shadow. If want to create a shadow behind your edittext box, you have to create a custom XML view in your res/drawable folder. Then set the attribute android:background="@drawable/*customFileName*" in your main.xml inside the edittext block. Here is a link to an answer to help you get started: [Add drop shadow effects to EditText Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850726/add-drop-shadow-effects-to-edittext-field)

Comment: i had already created an xml and made it the background for my edit text but i didn't reach to the same as the picture

Comment: Can you edit your question to share your code so that we can see your resource files and what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in xml :

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/shadowed_text_field" 
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 

        android:shadowColor="@color/#99a7b3c6"
        android:shadowDx="1.2"
        android:shadowDy="1.2"
        android:shadowRadius="1.5" 

        android:background="@color/white"/>
```

Comment: it doesn't give me the same as the picture

Comment: I do not see shadow on your picture. Play a bit with android:shadow... values to achieve desired effect. You should change black color too

Comment: I changed color from black to some blurred blue color

Comment: @BlackAndWhite I am emcountering same issue as urs .. did u find some solution for it?