# android:How to show drop shadow on an EditText view?

Tags: android

I apply elevation attribute and a drawable background which supply a rounded outline to the `EditText View`, but there is no shadow as expected.

[image: UI in AVD]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="#FAFAFA"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_search_icon"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search_icon"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the background rounded_edittext.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="27.5dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="27.5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="27.5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="27.5dp"/>
    <stroke android:color="#66000000" android:width="0.5dp"/>
</shape>
```

**UPDATE**

Below is the original design.

border color #000000 opacity 10(0~100)
shadow color #000000 opacity 5(0~100)
[image: UI]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add drop shadow effects to EditText Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850726/add-drop-shadow-effects-to-edittext-field)

Answer (score 2):

Replace your rounded_edittext.xml with the following code:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            <corners android:radius="27.5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <corners android:radius="27.5dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0.5dp"
                android:color="#66000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Also, replace `android:elevation="20dp"` from **EditText** with `android:elevation="4dp"`

Answer (score 1):

Go here : [Android View shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211870/android-view-shadow)

Or if you want to a put shadow under your view, add the following

In your Layout.xml

```
<View android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dropshadow"/>
```

drawble/dropshadow.xml >

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:endColor="#88333333"
        android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: In this case, you can't directly apply the gradient as a background. You need to add the gradient background as `<item>`  in  `<layer-list>`.

Comment: I'm not suggesting to put it as an EditText background, You have to add this in a <View>'s Background for some effect under the perticular view so...

Also i'm not using multiple items so no need to put <item> and <layer-list>, try this code by putting in some xml file and use it first.