# Correct text color/appearance in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I am struggling around with this problem for quite a long time. I searched for solutions and there were actually some suggestions for related problems, but nothing really worked correctly for me. So let's say I want to create an AlertDialog with a (long) message, a checkbox and two buttons.

```
// create dialog
AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
dlg.setTitle(R.string.dlg_title);
dlg.setMessage(R.string.dlg_msg);

// add checkbox
final CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
dlg.setView(checkbox);

// add buttons
dlg.setPositiveButton(...);
dlg.setNegativeButton(...);

// show dialog
dlg.show();
```

This **won't work**, because if the dialog message becomes too long, the checkbox will not be completely shown. Additionally, it is going to be completely hidden in landscape mode.

Next try would be to lookup the [original dialog layout file](https://code.google.com/p/pdn-slatedroid/source/browse/trunk/eclair/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/alert_dialog.xml?r=44) (for me it is located under android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-17/data/res/layout/alert_dialog.xml) and attempt to copy the relevant part to create our own "clone" of the inner dialog layout, just like this:

**dialog_checkbox.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
        android:paddingBottom="12dip"
        android:paddingLeft="14dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="2dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" />
    </ScrollView>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

We could try to add this view to our dialog like this:

```
// create dialog
AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
dlg.setTitle(R.string.dlg_title);

// add checkbox
LinearLayout checkboxLayout = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.dialog_checkbox, null);
((TextView) checkboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.message)).setText(R.string.dlg_msg);
mCheckbox = (CheckBox) checkboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
mCheckbox.setText(R.string.dlg_checkbox_msg);
setView(checkboxLayout);

// add buttons
dlg.setPositiveButton(...);
dlg.setNegativeButton(...);

// show dialog
dlg.show();
```

This actually works **quite** well. Almost. We will not see any problem until we use Theme.Light for our app. But as soon as we use Theme.Light, the dialog text colors will become black and unreadable on the dark background. **WHY?!**

- We've cloned the original Android alert dialog xml layout source code. But although we use attr/textAppearanceMedium as a text style, the text color becomes black under Theme.Light anyway.
- If we use Theme.Light and create a "normal" dialog with a normal message via setMessage, the text color is white and readable.

What's wrong? How to solve this? I don't want to programmatically set the text color to white or black, this will not look good on custom user themes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem and solved it by creating a ContextThemeWrapper for my desired Dialog Theme and used this when creating the AlertDialog Builder and when inflating the View to attach:

```
ContextThemeWrapper wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.DialogBaseTheme);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(wrapper);
View view = LayoutInflater.from(wrapper).inflate(R.layout.create_warning, null); 
builder.setView(view);
```

The style R.style.DialogBaseTheme is defined in "/values/styles.xml" for Gingerbread and below as:

```
<style name="DialogBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog"/>
```

Then it is also defined in "/values-v11/styles.xml" for Honeycomb and upward to use the Holo theme as:

```
<style name="DialogBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog" />
```

So on Gingerbread my custom View's TextViews are automatically coloured white and Honeycomb+ they are automatically coloured black for Holo Light.

Answer (score 1):

I **THINK** I finally found out how to solve it. On the basis of my initial code, this seems to solve my problem:

```
// add checkbox layout
LinearLayout checkboxLayout = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog), R.layout.dialog_checkbox, null);
((TextView) checkboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.message)).setText(DIALOG_TEXT);
mCheckbox = (CheckBox) checkboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
mCheckbox.setText(CHECKBOX_NOT_AGAIN);
setView(checkboxLayout);
```

Note the ContextThemeWrapper. It makes that the dialog theme is assigned to the inflated layout. I hope, this finally solves that problem for the future.

Comment: Nope. Seems like it does not work on Android 4... Goddamn. Can anyone please find a proper solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just inside textview add one attribute:

```
android:textColor="@color/white"
```

and define white color inside colors.xml which is inside res/values folder

```
<color name="white">#ffffff</color>
```

Or you may add directly

`android:textColor="#fffff"`(though not recommended.Above method is recommended.)

Comment: As said, I don't prefer this solution. What, if somebody uses a custom theme, where dialogs have a light background and a dark text color? They are going to have problems then. This solution is not clean at all in my opinion.

Comment: no you can try this because if u will give textcolor white explicitly , it will override any theme's default color.

Comment: You don't understand. Some Android users have custom ROMs and some of those custom ROMs are individually themed. And some of those individual themes might have very bright colors. And some of those bright-colored themes might have bright dialog backgrounds. And those themes who have bright dialog backgrounds will logically use dark text colors to make dialog text readable. And if I override this text colors with white, there will be white text shown on a bright background. Would you be able to read white text on a white background? I don't think so...

Comment: @user1684030 in that case you can create a custom xml file and set it's background to black and textview color to white.It will work fine.

Comment: Well, then the text might be readable, but it still would look ugly and unusual to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a **custom style** with a **shadow** to make your text visible whatever the text color is:

```
<resources>
<style name="Text.Shaded.Medium" parent="@android:attr/textAppearanceMedium">
    <item name="@android:paddingLeft">4dp</item>
    <item name="@android:paddingBottom">4dp</item>
    <item name="@android:textColor">#FFFFFFFF</item>
    <item name="@android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="@android:shadowDx">2</item>
    <item name="@android:shadowDy">2</item>
    <item name="@android:shadowRadius">2</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

**However** if it isn't visible enough for you you can apply an inner shadow, but unfortunately Android doesn't have a property for that so you'll have to use something like [MagicTextView](http://qwerjk.com/magic-text) (mentioned by [ABentSpoon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187455/abentspoon) in this question: [Is there a way to add inner shadow to a TextView on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871301/is-there-a-way-to-add-inner-shadow-to-a-textview-on-android)).

Comment: This solution also messes around with the default dialog look. It makes the dialog appearance unusuable and strange to the user. I don't prefer such a solution.